# How can I see that an issue has been moved between columns in a project using the GitHub GraphQL API?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql, github-projects

I'd like to determine when a card has moved from one column to another in a [GitHub Project Board](https://help.github.com/articles/about-project-boards/) using the GitHub GraphQL API.

I can list all issues in a project board (for example, [Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/projects/4#card-4924296)) using a query like this one:

```
{
  organization(login: "twbs") {
    repository(name: "bootstrap") {
      project(number: 4) {
        columns(first: 5) {
          nodes {
            name
            cards(first: 10) {
              nodes {
                content {
                  __typename
                  ... on Issue {
                    title
                    url
                    timeline(first: 10) {
                      nodes {
                        __typename
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are [many types of events](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/union/issuetimelineitem/) in the [`IssueTimelineConnection`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/issuetimelineconnection/), but project-related events are not among them:

```
...
{
  "content": {
    "__typename": "Issue",
    "title": "Remove inner white border effect on popovers",
    "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23763",
    "timeline": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "__typename": "RenamedTitleEvent"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "IssueComment"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "LabeledEvent"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "LabeledEvent"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "IssueComment"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "CrossReferencedEvent"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "CrossReferencedEvent"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "LabeledEvent"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ClosedEvent"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "CrossReferencedEvent"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
...
```

I can see when issues have been moved between columns on GitHub's web page for the issue:

[image]

I just can't see these events in the API. Is this a missing feature? Is there another way to get at this information? (Context: I'd like to build a [burndown chart for GitHub Project Boards](https://github.com/radekstepan/burnchart/pull/130).)

Comment: There is a mysterious `MovedColumnsInProjectEvent` but [it's an orphan](https://platform.github.community/t/how-can-movedcolumnsinprojectevent-events-be-queried/3396?u=danvk).

Comment: … and evidently [not very useful](https://platform.github.community/t/how-can-movedcolumnsinprojectevent-events-be-queried/3396/5?u=danvk).

Comment: Hi @danvk did you ever find a solution for this? The github community link is dead, I have pretty much the exact same use case, simply knowing that there _was_ a MovedColumnsInProjectEvent isnt really helpful. Is there a way to actually get this [MovedColumnsInProjectEvent](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/movedcolumnsinprojectevent/#implements) object?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the column and the last column change date by using the following query for the `new projects`. This method is `not valid` for `classic projects` in GitHub. The `updatedAt` field will give the update last column change date.

```
query{
  user(login: "USER_NAME") {
    projectV2(number: 1) {
      title
      items(first: 100) {
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
        nodes {
          content {
            ... on Issue {
              id
              title
              url
              state
              repository {
                name
                owner {
                  login
                }
              }
            }
          }
          status: fieldValueByName(name: "Status") {
            ... on ProjectV2ItemFieldSingleSelectValue {
              column: name
              updatedAt
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query was tested using [GitHub Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Accept header for Project Event Details (https://developer.github.com/v4/previews/#project-event-details) **and** the Accept header for Issue Preview(https://developer.github.com/v4/previews/#issues-preview)

Then you can use `timelineItems` and run a query like this:

```
query {
  repository(owner: "buildo", name: "react-components") {
    issue(number: 1321) {
      timelineItems(first: 10) {
        nodes {
          __typename
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
{
  "repository": {
    "issue": {
      "timelineItems": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "__typename": "ConvertedNoteToIssueEvent"
          },
          {
            "__typename": "AssignedEvent"
          },
          {
            "__typename": "LabeledEvent"
          },
          {
            "__typename": "MovedColumnsInProjectEvent"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```