# Is it possible to use the Github CLI to find out when an issue in a board has moved from one column to the next?

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli

I'm writing a script for tracking issues in a board on Github. There is a json field `updatedAt`, that allows me to know when an issue has been updated, but I need to know if that update was because it moved from one column to another, specifically from "InProgress" to a column called "Done".

The github CLI does not seem to expose this information, but in the Github UI you can see exactly when all events occur on an issue -- so theoretically it's possible, but maybe someone (me?) needs to write a github cli extension to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exact column changed time using the `GitHub GraphQL API`, but not sure about the GitHub cli though.
You can see the query for this in the following question.

[How can I see that an issue has been moved between columns in a project using the GitHub GraphQL API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294279/how-can-i-see-that-an-issue-has-been-moved-between-columns-in-a-project-using-th/75229873#75229873)